# C++ : How differs type* varName from type *varName?

Tags: c++

I am purely new to C++, I did Java 10 years ago and between this I used mainly R and Perl.

Now I have to extend the code written by someone and I am confused with the using of the pointer operator"*".

Is there a difference between writing it at the end of the type (f.e. "unsigned char* thing"), or writing it at the beginning of the variables name (f.e. "unsigned char *thing")?

Even in books the "grammar" seems to differ, what leads me to a "should not differ" meaning, but I want to be sure, so I ask you...

Comment: There is no difference whatsoever.

Comment: The reasons why some people prefer to write it next to the variable is due to how the compiler parses such a definition (usually from inner to outer). E.g `int *abc` reads as "declare a variable abc which is a pointer to an object of type `int`)